# Masking Reserved Words in Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, java, escape-characters

I have a Java program that I need to launch with a command like this:

```
java -cp "some.jar;some2.jar" -Dsome.prop.dir=C:\somedir com.software.MainClass
```

Now the issue here is the `-Dsome.prop.dir=C:\somedir` parameter - for some reason it causes Java to fail with `Could not find or load main class com.software.MainClass`. If I leave out that one parameter, the program starts up fine, but obviously, the poperty is not set.

I'm guessing it's maybe beacause `dir` is a reserved word in Windows. Is there any way to perhaps mask it or work around this, other than changing the Java application or crafting some special binary/PE launcher for the Java application in Windows?

Comment: This isn’t a reserved word issue.  The problem is your syntax, you have a space, outside quotes.

Comment: @Ramhound Erm what space?

Comment: “**somedir com**” the quotes are still missing

Comment: @Ramhound They are separate arguments

Comment: @Ramhound `com.software.MainClass` is the name of the classfile to run.

Comment: Try the following command line `java -cp "some.jar;some2.jar" -Dsome.prop.dir="C:\somedir" com.software.MainClass`

Comment: @DavidPostill That's not it,  `-Dsome.prop.dir="C:\somedir"` and `-Dsome.prop.dir=a` fail just the same. As does `"-Dsome.prop.dir=a"` as does `"-Dsome.prop.dir"="a"` - otoh, `-Dsome.prop.adir=C:\somedir` works.

Comment: You should also try `-Dsome.prop.dir=C:\\somedir` putting two backslashes in folder paths or otherwise use the forward slash instead like `-Dsome.prop.dir=C:/somedir`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution, but some tests and recommendations to investigate your problem.

I attempted to reproduce the problem you describe. I even created the bogus names (directory somedir, class Mainclass).

Here's my version of Mainclass. Essentially, it gets the system property, and uses it to generate some simple diagnostic output.

```
package com.software;

import java.io.File;

public class Mainclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String someDir = System.getProperty("some.prop.dir");
        if (someDir == null || someDir.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No directory parameter specified");            
        } else {
            File dir = new File(someDir);
            System.out.println(String.format("Directory stats: %s, %s, %s", someDir, dir.getAbsolutePath(), dir.isDirectory() ? "directory" : "file"));
        }
        System.out.println("Main running okay.");
    }      
}
```

Next, I created a jar file containing Mainclass, and named it some.jar.

I ran the command line as follows:

```
java -cp "some.jar" -Dsome.prop.dir=C:\somedir com.software.Mainclass
```

Results:
        Directory stats: C:\somedir, C:\somedir, directory
        Main running okay.

I also ran without the -D parameter:

```
java -cp "some.jar" com.software.Mainclass
```

Results:
        No directory parameter specified
        Main running okay.

Although I was able to run the problem without issue, I saw a few places where the problem could exist:

1. The jar files. You are specifying the classpath to be those first 2 file names. Mainclass needs to be in one of them or it will not be found. I suspect this is not the issue, since it runs correctly without the -D parameter.
2. The -D parameter is used internally to locate the class. In the sample code above, I'm just reporting on the directory. Perhaps you are using it to locate the class file somehow, and it cannot find it? Perhaps the program uses the directory to look for the class, but when you omit the directory, it defaults to using the one specified in the jar file?

If I ran in the bin directory (where the classes were generated), I was able to omit the -cp command and it ran correctly.

If I used -cp with a jar without Mainclass, I got the error, but I got it whether or not -D was specified.